# Mocha testing using expectjs, getting model to match hash?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

Currently I'm doing this:

```
expect( tasks.at(0).get('title') ).to.be('Root')
expect( tasks.at(0).get('next') ).to.be(true)
```

But it seems like there should be a better way. I'd rather do something like this:

```
expect(tasks.at(0).attributes).to.eql({title:'Root', next:true})
```

But that doesn't work because `tasks.at(1).attributes` has many other attributes, so it doesn't strictly match. Any ideas? I'm fine with using something other than expectjs.

Comment: I would say perform a for-in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way, but I took the advice from @skizeey and made my own test extension. In other words, now I call (in coffeescript):

```
expect(tasks).to.have.modelAttributes
  1: title:'Root'
  2: title:'Child'
```

The code I used is pretty specific to the testing library I am using (switched to Chai), but the general idea is that I iterate over the hash, extract the index, and then look at each key:value. Here's a generic example of my code:

```
    # Check each index
    for index of properties
        # Iterate over each key:value in each index
        for key of properties[index]
```